# Random vertical bars on screen

Tags: windows-7, display, hardware-failure

I have an HP laptop with Windows 7 running on 2 GB RAM and a 500 GB HDD. I occasionally get problems like vertical lines filling my screen (white screen with black and blue lines) and a completely blank screen.

When I get these problems, the system becomes unresponsive. I have to shut it down manually using the power button. But, when I restart, everything works just fine.
Thinking it was my OS giving me these problems, I formatted and re-installed the OS, but this did not fix the issue.

I am sure it is not an overheating issue, because I get these problems rarely and these problems sometimes occur when I leave my PC on for long time and sometimes immediately after fresh boot.

I am confused.
What should I do?

Comment: have you checked the graphics card? Could it be an issue with the graphics driver? When the system goes unresponsive, eg can you still hear sound?

Comment: i left the music playing in the background and started using my pc...after about half an hour i got the blank screen, i had wifi and power indicator lights on and it was blank and black though i could feel lights on the screen, error...and the music stopped. the system became unresponsive. and i had to manually shutdown the pc using power button. any suggestions?